Convert datetime works fine, unless I Order by the converted column
select x, convert(datetime,datecolumn) + convert(datetime,timecolumn) as datetime
from abc
where d = e

This works fine, I can see all of the columns and the dates and times have added to combine from:
'2003-01-02' & '19:40' to -> '2003-01-02 19:40:00.000'
When I go to Order by the new date column, however:
select x, convert(datetime,datecolumn) + convert(datetime,timecolumn) as datetime
from abc
where d = e
order by datetime desc

I get:

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I've tried setting different date styles of 21, 25 or 12 for the convert, as per this MS document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
But I just get a different error:

The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.


SSMS is just an IDE (like) application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

As for the problem, can you please take the time to provide a [mre], with consumable sample data (DDL and DML statements).

Why do you want to convert a datetime to a date and a time and put them back together?

What happens if you remove where d = e from the original query? If you get an error then there are some values in the table which fail conversion (despite being filtered in the where).


Updated to include Microsoft SQL 2016
Clarified the column names in the conversion
I'm not, I'm converting date, and time, into datetime
I still get the error without the 'where' clause


The point is more - the conversion is clearly working fine, so much so that addition of the time to the date is successful, so why can't I sort? And instead get a conversion error when I try to? If it's already worked?

It's not entirely clear here '2003-01-02' & '19:40' should be -> '2003-01-0219:40:00.000'. Can you give a more accurate quote?

I have added the date (2003-01-02 00:00:00.000) to the time (1900-01-01 19:40:00.000) with the '+' addition function, to make the datetime (2003-01-02 19:40:00.000)

There is no string concatenation

convert(datetime,(a+' ' + b))

There is no concatenation, I am adding datetime to datetime to produce a new datetime, this works correctly. It only stops working when sorted.

Probably what is happening is that in the normal case the filter removes any invalid values that can't be converted to datetime. Introducing the order by generates a different plan, where the conversion is attempted before the filter, and it breaks because some rows (where d <> e) contain garbage. Please construct a repro on db<>fiddle with the data types (and explain why you aren't storing these as datetime or similar in the first place).

Because they come from multiple 3rd party sources, ok yes I see I also had a "top x" limit, when I remove this and the "where" clause, it finds a dud entry and errors, even without the grouping. Ok thank you for explaining this to me!

Test with try_convert to identify and/or exclude rows with invalid data.  Just assuming everything is going to work will get you into trouble.

Probably what is happening is that in the normal case the filter removes any invalid values that can't be converted to datetime. Introducing the order by generates a different plan, where the conversion is attempted before the filter, and it breaks because some rows (where d <> e) contain garbage.
To guard against processing order, you can use TRY_CONVERT(), e.g.
SELECT x, TRY_CONVERT(datetime,datecolumn) 
        + TRY_CONVERT(datetime,timecolumn) as datetime
  FROM dbo.abc
  WHERE d = e
  ORDER BY datetime DESC;

Of course, to identify rows with garbage so you can fix them and maybe even prevent them in the future, you could find them this way:
SELECT x, datecolumn, timecolumn
  FROM dbo.abc
 WHERE
       (
         datecolumn IS NOT NULL 
         AND
         TRY_CONVERT(datetime, datecolumn) IS NULL
       )
    OR
       (
         timecolumn IS NOT NULL 
         AND
         TRY_CONVERT(datetime, timecolumn) IS NULL
       );

Though datetime + datetime is not a great practice, since this will start breaking if you ever switch to datetime2, for example. You should also pressure your 3rd party sources to provide data in date/time columns; that's why we have them (and it would stop garbage earlier in the process).
